# Notification message not displaying after a bash script runs on Mac OS X

Tags: bash, applescript, launchd

I have a Launchdaemon and script that deletes an application upon download of it from the App store.

So the app downloads and it auto deletes upon download. A notification message to the end user should display but it does not. Can anyone help?

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

Version=$(sw_vers | grep ProductVersion | tail -c 7 | cut -d . -f 2)    

if [ $Version -ge 12 ]
then  
launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/net.sierra.plist
rm -f /Library/LaunchDaemons/net.sierra.plist
rm -f /usr/local/bin/sierra.sh
exit 0

else
rm -rf /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Sierra.app/
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog "macOS Sierra is not allowed on computers at this time."'
fi
```

I would add that if i create a test directory called
/Applications/Install\ macOS\ Sierra.app    it auto deletes it AND you get the display message.

thanks

Comment: Are you sure about the path and name ? For Yosemite it was "Applications/Installer\ OS\ X\ Yosemite" and for El Capitain it was "Applications/Installer\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitain". Except that,I think it could be that process is in background. Did you try using a 'tell app "Finder" '. Last detail you should add : with icon 0 buttons {"OK"} default button "OK" (it will give you the stop icon with only 1 button instead of Cancel/OK.

Comment: I would use a find command to search for the "Sierra.app".  Regardless of its path, if it exists and the version is of a desired number, then remove it. Let me know if you need help on the syntax.

Comment: @pbell - yes the path and name is correct. I also tried "finder" with same issue.

Comment: @misteralexander - thats sounds useful, yes if you can help with that it would be great. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    VERSION=$(sw_vers | grep ProductVersion | tail -c 7 | cut -d . -f 2)

    if [[ "$VERSION" -ge '12' ]]
        then
            echo "TRUE LOGIC RUNNING"
            #launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/net.sierra.plist
            #rm -f /Library/LaunchDaemons/net.sierra.plist
            #rm -f /usr/local/bin/sierra.sh
        else
            echo "FALSE LOGIC RUNNING"
            #find '/Applications' -type 'f' -name 'Sierra.app' -exec rm -f '{}' \;         #osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog "macOS Sierra is not allowed on computers at this time."'
    fi
```

You can uncomment the code once you can see which logic section is running. Then, step through it and troubleshoot step by step to see where your errors are.

Also, you don't need `exit 0` as the script will exit with a status zero code automatically.  If you have logic testing status codes, you will usually want to put `exit 1` so some other running process can feed that into its logic.

Comment: I used your script and neither the .app deletes or the message appears.  I've tried uncommenting each line and the same issue occurs. I'm not sure what you mean where you can see which "logic section is running" ?

Comment: Yes, as is, you should see a message (in Terminal) that says either "TRUE LOGIC RUNNING" or "FALSE LOGIC RUNNING".  You'll get the true message if your "Version" is greater than or equal to '12', you'll see the false message if your version is below 12.  Since these are "echo" statements, you're only going to see them in Terminal and not in a GUI pop-up or something.

Comment: Additionally, I found [this link](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sw_vers.1.html) that explains that you can run "sw_vers -productVersion" directly instead of a tail and cut to get the version number.  Just a thought to reduce the steps needed.